# Why does a mingw-compiled Game Maker extension crash on exit when compiled without -static?

Tags: dll, mingw, game-maker

I compile a DLL with mingw 4.5.0 and use it as a Game Maker 8.0 extension. Game Maker dynamically loads the dll. Everything appears to work (the dll functions are called and provide correct return values), but when I close Game Maker a dialog pops up: "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library", "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way." After that, the process continues to linger in the background for a few seconds and then disappears.

This also happens when none of the functions of the dll are actually called. There is no `DllMain`, and all static/global variables are basic data types or `std::string` (it actually also happens when I remove the std::strings).

The dll statically links with zlib and libpng. The problem seems to vanish when I pass -static to the linker which (I assume) also links the runtime statically. However, this considerably inflates the size of my DLL, and it is at best a workaround until I understand what is going on.

Any ideas on what might be the cause?

**Update**: Actually, it seems that the problem only happens when two extensons are loaded in Game Maker: One with a dll linked with -static, and the other without. Linking both without -static makes the problem disappear. However, I still don't understand the problem, because the dlls never directly interact or share data structures.

**Update 2**: I recently found out that this might be related to strange behavior of Game  Maker itself. It seems that global variables aren't initialized correctly when the DLL is loaded, which might cause a crash on unloading if global objects try to free memory they don't own. That would mean the -static was just a random factor that changed the value of the uninitialized memory the globals were associated with.

**Update 3**: Modified the above to include the info that this is about Game Maker extensions, since this is likely relevant as per Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess. Try to look into something like the "static initialization order fiasco" that is described [here](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.12). It may be that your problem is more related to the destructors (since it happens on close).